# AWS LambdaException Unable to Load Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.0

This is my first AWS Lambda function. I've worked through most of the knowledge gap, but I'm stuck on this error I get from both the Test method when uploading the function and from the API Gateway test method.

I uploaded this as a zip file vs some of the other publish methods because I'm using .NET Core 2.0 and the wizard in VS 2017 only has .NET Core 1.0 as an option.

`Error:
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Unable to load type 'WebApplication2.LambdaEntryPoint' from assembly 'WebApplication2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
}`

`public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .Build();`

```
        builder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<DependencyResolution.Startup>()
            .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, typeof(LambdaEntryPoint).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName) // Ignore the startup class assembly as the "entry point" and instead point it to this app
           .UseApiGateway(); 
    }
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda supports *only* .NET Core 1.0. You cannot use .NET Core 2.0 (at least at this time - support will probably come in a bit).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed it to .NET Core 1.0 and it at least uploaded. On to the next obstacle!